# What css property can i use to make my bounce animation much more smoother ?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have a simple bounce in animation for my `figure` , see HTML below:

```
<figure>
  <img src="http://unilaboralgirona.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ZContact.jpg" alt="">
  <figcaption>
    <!-- empty for now -->
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

My CSS animation is as follows:

```
@keyframes drop-in-thumb {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50px);
        -o-transform: translateY(-50px);
        transform: translateY(-50px);
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    35% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        -o-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    55% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
        -o-transform: translateY(-15px);
        transform: translateY(-15px);
    }
    70% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    85% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
        -o-transform: translateY(-5px);
        transform: translateY(-5px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        -o-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

The fiddle can be seen **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ssexmh3s/1/)**.

The problem is my animation is quite jerky , I.E. it does't have a realistic bounce in effect , it looks clearly quite jerky. My question is what other property in the keyframes apart form the % breakpoints can i use to tweak and make my animation smooth ?

Tweaking the % breakpoints really helped me make the animation much more smoother and but its really not yet realistic yet. What other  CSS animation property can i use to make this animation smoother ?

It would be great if somebody could demonstrate how i could perfect and make this animation much more smoother.

P.S. i am aware of the library animate.css but don't want to use it.

Comment: Try using a different `animation-timing-function`. The default `linear` will be quite chopping. `ease-in-out` might be ideal.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol hmmmm thanks for the suggestions , let me look into that ! :)

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik: Or even custom easing functions using `cubic-bezier` could be helpful. By the way, I am on Chrome and the animation doesn't really look all that jerky. Its fairly smooth.

Comment: if you have specific stops in your keyframes you should look into the the  cubic-bezier option (animation-timing-function property )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [animation-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) property should improve this considerably.

Try adding the following to the styles for `figure`:

```
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

I've edited your fiddle to show the difference: https://jsfiddle.net/ssexmh3s/2/